# My C# Windows Form Application is blank?

Tags: c#

I'm Making A windows form application , And everytime I Excute it , All i see is a blank form , My project is named frmMain.cs and this is the header that i use :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class frmMain : Form
{
private TextBox txtYear;
private Button btnCheck;
private Button btnClose;
private Label label1;
#region windows code
private void IntitializeComonent()
{
}
#endregion
public frmMain()
{
    IntitializeComonent();
}
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    frmMain main = new frmMain();
    Application.Run(main);
}


 private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.txtYear = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
    this.btnCheck = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // label1
    // 
    this.label1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 24);
    this.label1.Name = "label1";
    this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(98, 20);
    this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.label1.Text = "Year To Test: ";
    this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    // 
    // txtYear
    // 
    this.txtYear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(129, 24);
    this.txtYear.Name = "txtYear";
    this.txtYear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
    this.txtYear.TabIndex = 1;
    // 
    // btnCheck
    // 
    this.btnCheck.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 93);
    this.btnCheck.Name = "btnCheck";
    this.btnCheck.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.btnCheck.TabIndex = 2;
    this.btnCheck.Text = "Leap Year?";
    this.btnCheck.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // btnClose
    // 
    this.btnClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(154, 93);
    this.btnClose.Name = "btnClose";
    this.btnClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.btnClose.TabIndex = 3;
    this.btnClose.Text = "&Close";
    this.btnClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // frmMain
    // 
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnClose);
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnCheck);
    this.Controls.Add(this.txtYear);
    this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
    this.Name = "frmMain";
    this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    this.Text = "Determain a Leap Year";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmMain_Load);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();

}

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

I also have a habit that i delete program.cs and frmMain.Designer.cs because i dont need them in my program , Does that have anything to do with my problem ? Help Please!

Comment: are you *sure* you are initializing the right form?

Comment: Yes, you very much need those files you deleted.

Comment: Try not to delete them. Does it work?

Comment: Those files you deleted are what is telling frmMain how to design itself.  Don't delete them

Comment: Didn't it say something along the lines of: "Do not edit this with the code editor" in comments above InitializeComponent() ?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman in his defense, he _deleted_ them.

Comment: Reminds me of my dad who under Windows 98 moved all files in `C:\ ` inside a folder because it looked so messy :).

Comment: As well as not deleting them, you seem to have moved them inside a `InitializeComponent` method that never gets called

Comment: @rik : Those files are optional. They just simply usage by keeping related stuff together. His code works fine after fixing the typo

Comment: it started working after i fixed the typo , thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `frmMain()` you're calling `InitializeComonent()` (which is empty) instead of calling `InitializeComponent()`. Probably just a typo.

Comment: You beat me to it...+1 :) I got a bit stuck on the formatting

Comment: @YousefAbuZahra Please mark one of the answers as the selected answer!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine. Just a small typo

```
public frmMain()
{
    // In your constructor change 'IntitializeComonent' to 'InitializeComponent'
    IntitializeComonent();
}
```